# Express Server how to post data from postman

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, postman, express-validator

I just built a express server with mongodb and trying to request it using postman but getting error
So this is the code for the  route

```
router.post(
    '/',
    check('email', 'Please include a valid email').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Password is required').exists(),
    async (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
          return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }
        const {email,password}=req.body;
        
        var FirstTimer= new User({
            email:email,
            password:password        
        });
        
        FirstTimer.save(function(err,result){
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            else{
                console.log(result)
            }
        })
    }
)
```

code for server.js

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
connectDB();/*connect to mongoose which in turn connect to db*/


app.use('/api/auth',require('./routes/api/auth'));


app.listen(port,()=>console.log('listening on 3000'))//mention port here
```

this is how i am sending the postman data and the error
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I was using JSON data, so I had to use `app.use(json())` in the server.js